# Regular expression to match start of an address

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match the start of an address in java. I have tried with this website (http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) and it did match the address but the very minute i tried it in netbean it did not.
any idea why?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\bcloud.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("cloud (cloud.yahoo.com:225) - v0.00014 ( jan 10 1999 / 24:12:56 )"); 

System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `address.startsWith("cloud")`?

Comment: Sorry dont know what you mean by address. Is there any class in java called address?

Comment: No. address is just your string.

Comment: I know what you mean now but the problem I am working on the=is solution would not work.

Answer (score 6):

`\` should be escaped. Otherwise `\b` is interpreted as *BACKSPACE* instead of *word boundary*.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bcloud.*");
//                           ^^^
```

See http://ideone.com/1rdLg6

Comment: It does work for netbean not for eclipse. I am trying to sort out some problem which involve windowTester. only eclipse has the windowTester plugin. thanks